# Installing CAB-files does not help to solve the "error message cannot be displayed ... optional resource assembly ... cannot be found"

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

So I have read a little on the problem with not getting decent error messages when running om Compact Framework (Windows Mobile) devices. I get the error:

> An error message cannot be displayed
>   because an optional resource assembly
>   containing it cannot be found.

Several sites, and also answers here on stackoverflow, references this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2004/08/06/210232.aspx

In that article it says that:

> If you are not using Visual Studio F5
>   deploy to the device and would still
>   like to see the    exception messages,
>   you can achieve this by taking the
>   System_SR_[Language].CAB  where
>   [Language] corresponds to the language
>   in which you want to see the error
>   message to appear and clicking on the
>   cab file to install it.

I copied the System_SR_ENU.cab and System_SR_ENU_wm.cab from location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\CompactFramework\2.0\v1.0\WindowsCE\Diagnostics

and installed the CAB-files (one at a time).
That, however, does not work. At all.

I have copied and installed two such cab-files from my Visual Studio directory. The installtion goes well, no errors, but nonetheless I still have the same error.

I am running devices that has WM 5.0 up till WM 6.5 and the devices ranges from Dell Axim v51 to HTC HD2 (and some stuff in between).

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a piece of software you have the source code for ? Have you tried extracting the cab and directly adding a reference to System.SR.dll directly within your project.  This has worked for me in the past when I have come across the odd stubborn device that would not work from the cab file.

I have only ever done this in a development environment so if you need to ship the error messages then you may be back to square one.

Comment: Yes, the code is all mine. And I have actually tried to reference that DLL, but nothing helps...

Comment: Have you tried upgrading or making a small test project in cf3.5 to see if the deployment of the string resources works for that. The package is slightly different and located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics\NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab

Comment: Thanks rggardner, I will take a look at this as soon as I can find some time, and reply here if it works =)